# Switching from street view to map view

Tags: javascript

I am playing around with the Google Maps API with an Amtrak route map. The map is at [this link](http://dmmarks.com/California%20Zephyr.html).

I found out that by dragging the person icon to the map you enter street view. How do you return to map view?

Comment: You mean, how to force the map to go to normal mode via a javascript code ?

Comment: it is not clear what you asking. But there's a div that allows you to return to map view. You can click it through js using this `document.getElementsByClassName('gm-iv-close')[0].click()`